# How do I remove all but the last 12 characters from filenames of different lengths using Mac terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, rename, filenames

How do I remove the last 12 characters from these files, and change it from this:

`RE0001_cdea_3000_001_000_0000.MP4`

`175c_3000_000_000_0000.MP4`

To this:

`001_000_0000.MP4`

`000_000_0000.MP4`

I'm guessing is the inverse of something like `for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:12}"; done`.  But that removed the first 12 characters, and since the file length will change, I'm hoping the start at the file type and count the left. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a negative offset counts from the end.

```
mv "$f" "${f: -12}"
```

Note that when using a negative offset you have to put a space before the offset. Otherwise it's interpreted as `${f:-defaultvalue}`

But it seems like you forgot to count the `.MP4` suffix, you want the last 16 characters.

```
mv "$f" "${f: -16}"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!  But using a `-` doesn't seem to work for me.  This changes the files names: `for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:16}"; done ` But adding the `-` doesn't do anything to the exact group of files : `for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:-16}"; done` Am I missing something?

Comment: Updated the answer. A space is needed before the offset when it's negative.

Comment: `${var:-}` is a different P.E. see `man bash | grep -FA1 '${parameter:-word}'` but this works as intended. `"${f:(-16)}"`

Comment: @Jetchisel That's the same point I was making when I explained why a space is used. Parens also work.